# How to build a wave spawner that spawns 3 enemies with independent timers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently building a wave base game in Unity, but I am currently stuck. My goal is to have 3 enemies spawning at different rates independently. I have one big class that manages the Waves and in which I store data like *Enemy1Count (How many Enemy1 spawn)*, *Enemy1Rate (At which rate they spawn)*. I want the first enemy to spawn every 2 seconds, the second enemy to spawn every 3 seconds and the third enemy to spawn every 5 seconds, but I can't make that happen without the timers affecting each other. Do you have any idea how I could solve that? (I would like to manage all the data for the 3 enemies within one class)

Comment: For each spawn type have a nextSpawn variable. Set the variable to the current time plus the spawn interval. Each frame check if the current time is greater or equal to the nextSpawn time. If it is spawn the object and set the nextSpawn to the current time plus the interval again.

Comment: You may want to consider a more modular approach where you have something like a SpawnManager class that contains a collection of spawners that are each responsible for their own behavior. It would be more flexible than having one monolithic class and you could easily swap out different spawners and their data without having to modify code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a problem where you can definitely use [Unity Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), you should be able to run a coroutine per enemy so it will spawn a wave after X amount of time.

Something like this should work for your logic

```
Coroutine c1, c2,c3;
bool keepSpawningEnemies = true;
Start(){
        c1= StartCoroutine(SpawnWave(enemy1, 3.0f));
        c2= StartCoroutine(SpawnWave(enemy2, 10.0f));
        c3= StartCoroutine(SpawnWave(enmey3, 5.0f));

}

IEnumerator SpawnWave(Enemy enemy, float timeBetweenWaves)
{
   while(keepSpawningEnemies ) {
      SpawnWaveLogic(enemy);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenWaves);
  }
}


Update() {

  // logic to check if we need to keep spawning
  // At some point you would run
  keepSpawningEnemies = false;

}
```

Comment: Thank you it finally works! I was trying to fit all 3 enemies into 1 Coroutine but splitting them in 3 seperate works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to create a component that is responsible for handling just one wave, then add three instances of that component to the scene.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Object prefab;
    [SerializeField] private float spawnInterval;

    private WaitForSeconds waitForNextSpawn;

    private void Awake() => waitForNextSpawn = new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);
    private void OnEnable() => StartCoroutine(SpawnLoop());
    private void OnDisable() => StopCoroutine(SpawnLoop());

    private IEnumerator SpawnLoop()
    {
        while(enabled)
        {
            yield return waitForNextSpawn;
            Instantiate(prefab);
        }
    }
}
```